# Differentials to derivatives involving trace of matrices

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, hadamard-product, scalar-fields

Suppose $P$ is a real-valued function of the $p\times m$ (real) matrix $\mathbf{Q}$. After taking its differential, one arrives with the following:

$$
  d(P(\mathbf{Q}))
   = \operatorname{trace}\left\{\mathbf{1}^\top_p\left[ d\mathbf{Q}\odot  \mathbf{W} \right]\left(\mathbf{w}\odot \mathbf{G}\right)\right\}
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_p$ is the $p\times 1$ vector of $1$'s with $\mathbf{W}$ is $p\times m$ while $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{G}$ are both $m \times 1$. $\mathbf{W}$, $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{G}$ are  matrices involving $\mathbf{Q}$.

**Question:** What is
$
   \dfrac{dP}{d\mathbf{Q}} 
$ ?

**Attempt:** $
   \dfrac{dP}{d\mathbf{Q}} = 
 \mathbf{W} \left(\mathbf{w}\odot \mathbf{G}\right)
\mathbf{1}_p
$

But I think it's wrong. So my problem really is that Hadamard product of $d\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{W} $.

Some identities I have found online are these:

> • $\dfrac{d(\mathbf{a}^\top\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b})} {d \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{a}  \mathbf{b}^\top$
>
> • $\operatorname{trace} (\mathbf{A}\odot \mathbf{B})\mathbf{C} = \operatorname{trace} \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{B}^\top \odot  \mathbf{C})$

**UPDATE:** To make it simpler, a general problem would be

$$
    \frac{\mathbf{a}^\top\left[d\mathbf{Q}\odot f(\mathbf{Q}) \right]g(\mathbf{Q})}{d\mathbf{Q}}
$$
where $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{R}^{p}$, $f:\mathbb{R}^{p\times m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^{p\times m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

The available identity I have encountered similar to this is

$$
  \frac{\operatorname{trace}(\mathbf{A}d\mathbf{X})}{d\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{A}
$$

from page 2 of this [link](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf).

Comment: Note that $1_p^T$ is a row vector and everything to the right of it is a matrix (lump it together and call it $M$). The quantity $r^T=1_p^TM$ is also a row vector. How do you define the trace of a row vector?

Comment: Thank you @greg for point out. I correted it already together with an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let 
$$\eqalign{
b &= w\odot G, \quad a &= 1_p \cr
}$$
Rearrange the given differential to isolate the gradient wrt $Q$.
$$\eqalign{
dP
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big(a^T\,(dQ\odot W)\,b\Big) \cr
 &= a^T\,(dQ\odot W)\,b \quad {\rm \{trace\,does\,not\,affect\,scalar\,values\}} \cr
 &= ab^T:(dQ\odot W) \cr
 &= (ab^T\odot W):dQ \cr
\frac{\partial P}{\partial Q} &= ab^T\odot W \cr
 &= \Big(1_p(w\odot G)^T\Big)\odot W \cr
}$$
where a colon is used to write the trace in product form, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}\big(A^TB\big)$$

**UPDATE**

The updated question uses $(f,g)$ in place of $(W,b)\,$  so the gradient becomes
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial P}{\partial Q} &= ag^T\odot f \cr
}$$

Comment: I apologize. Prior to my edit, I have written that $\mathbf{W}$ also involves $\mathbf{Q}$, i.e., it is not constant with respect to $\mathbf{Q}$. I have edited it now.

Comment: Yes, but you also provided the differential $dP$ in which all those dependencies have been sorted out. The differential only contains the $dQ$ term. If that differential is correct, then the gradient above is correct.

Comment: But I can't seem to get pass with the third line of yours : $X = Q\odot W \implies dX = dQ\odot W$ where $X$ has just been introduced while the equality involving $dP$ has already been established prior to it. Did I miss something? Shouldn't that be product rule since $W$ involves $Q$?

Comment: I changed the name of my variable from $P$ to $\phi$. The **important** point is that their differentials are equal.

Comment: The $X$ variable was a distraction. It has been removed.